# Need help adding a bookmark to Delicious using cURL

Tags: php, curl, delicious-api

I'm trying to write a class that can add a bookmark to my Delicious account.
Here's my method:

```
public function addBookmark($url, $description) {   
    $dusername = 'myUsername';  
    $dpassword = 'myPassword';  
    $api = 'api.del.icio.us/v1';  
    $link = urlencode($url);  
    $desc = urlencode($description);  
    $apicall = "https://$dusername:$dpassword@$api/posts/add?&url=$link&description=$desc";  
    $ch = curl_init($apicall);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'php - curl');  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    $xml = curl_exec($ch);   
}
```

In the real code, $dusername and $dpassword are my actual credentials.

When called from PHP, it fails to add a bookmark. However if I echo $apicall, and go to it directly with FireFox, the bookmark is added. So, this makes me assume there's an error in my cURL implementation. I tried commenting out the lines where it sets `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`, but that didn't work either.

This is driving me crazy because at first I rolled my own code, which didn't work. Now I'm using code someone has (allegedly) got working for themselves, and still no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: Sadly, no. I wish I was. I was using curl_getinfo(), but it didn't spit any error messages out. The Delicious API is supposed to return an XML response, but I wasn't receiving any.

Comment: This is what curl_error() returned: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a problem verifying the Certificate Authority's certificate. Not sure how you fix this but you might be able to sidestep it like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```